# JSON in Servlets

Tags: json, servlets

I want to make a json array in Servlet from a result set. If any one has some idea about this , please suggest me ?

Comment: There are JSON implementations for Java: http://www.json.org/java/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different JSON-libraries available for java, see [here](http://www.json.org/) (scroll down the page, the list is near the bottom).